# How can I identify the button I click on the grid with a nested list of names? Python - .Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I currently have a grid of buttons with rows and columns(using a for loop) and want to be able to click one of these buttons and it return, for instance, a1 is clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
#list I need that attributes grid index to button name
#seats=[["A", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"]["B", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]["C", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"], ["D", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"]]

def make_buttons():

    for r in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            btn = tk.Button(root, text="Empty")
            btn['command'] = lambda c=c, r=r, b=btn:red_click(c, r, b)
            btn.grid(row=r,column=c)

def red_click(c, r, btn):
    print(btn, "clicked!")
    btn.configure(bg="red")


root = tk.Tk()

make_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

I expect it to return to me which button was clicked.

I've tried making it so that it prints it, but I can't certainly identify buttons as it shows, i.e., .!Button25 clicked!

Comment: You can pass the text along the same way you passed the row, column and button instance.

Comment: send text to `red_click` as argument. If it is text on button then you can get `btn['text']`

Comment: BTW: function assigned to button can't return anything - it can only diplay on screen or assign value to global variable.

Comment: BTW: you have pair `r,c` so you should recognize which button you clicked. ie. `seats[r][c]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind values to arbitrary attributes on the `Button` object. Then you can retrieve that value using an attribute lookup.

Also, it would be better to use the seating plan held in the `seats` list to create the buttons. You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to help iterate over the values while still having access to the indices that you need for the grid:

```
import tkinter as tk

seats= [["A", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"],
        ["B", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"],
        ["C", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"],
        ["D", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"]]

def make_buttons():
    for r, row in enumerate(seats):
        for c, seat in enumerate(row[1:]):        # N.B. skip first element
            btn = tk.Button(root, text="Empty")
            btn.name = seat                       # arbitrary attribute on Button object
            btn['command'] = lambda c=c, r=r, b=btn:red_click(c, r, b)
            btn.grid(row=r,column=c)

def red_click(c, r, btn):
    print(btn.name, "clicked!")
    btn.configure(bg="red")

root = tk.Tk()
make_buttons()
root.mainloop()
```

---

For many objects Python lets you create "arbitrary" attributes on the object from outside of the class itself. E.g.

```
class C:
    pass

>>> c = C()
>>> c.whatever
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: C instance has no attribute 'whatever'
>>> c.whatever = 'hi there'
>>> c.whatever
'hi there'
```

Comment: You helped me in 2 ways. 1.) it works! 2.) you introduced me to enumerate, which is NEEDED. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnHenderson: no problem.

Comment: @JohnHenderson: you can read about `enumerate` in the Python documentation - link provided in answer.

Comment: @JohnHenderson: updated answer to better demonstrate assigning to an arbitrary attribute on an object.

Answer (score 1):

In `red_click` you have pair `r,c` so you can get `seats[r][c]`